# Why aren't high-rep users able to post from IP addresses that are automatically banned?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, policy

As explicitly stated in the last section of [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998) (emphasis mine),

> #### My account is in good standing. Why am I still blocked?
>
> The ban also takes in account the IP address. If you browse from a shared computer, or from a location that gives the same IP address to many end users, it's enough that another user who was banned or triggers the ban, **will affect everyone else** accessing from the same location.
>
> To help rectify this, browse from a different location.

even Jon Skeet cannot ask questions on a shared network where someone else has made the IP address banned from asking.

While this rarely happens, it's quite possible in certain cases:

- You're such an unlucky cat that you got a banned IP address from your ISP
- Someone behind the same NAT as you are behaves badly. This could be a common case in corporate network, or dense apartment buildings
- People using public VPN services to circumvent some firewalls. Also a common case to some extents. All users behind the same VPN server are banned

For points 2 and 3, there usually are unavoidable reasons for such users to visit SE under the given network environment, and being banned from asking or answering *just for* visiting from a "bad" IP address could be frustrating.

What was originally taken into account when making this decision, instead of granting "IP ban exception" to users with good histories (e.g. "trusted user"s with 20k+ or 4k+ on beta sites)?

Comment: "even Jon Skeet cannot ask questions on a shared network where someone else has made the IP address banned from asking" - I don't believe this is accurate. It's my understanding that IP-level restrictions only impact new accounts or those below a (low) reputation threshold. This is true even for spam / trolling IP blocks, in an effort to minimize the collateral damage you describe for established members of the site.

Comment: 125 points of reputation is [the stated threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/259942/19679) for where you stop experiencing IP-level question rate limiting, and it was my understanding that a similar threshold applied for the other IP-level limits.

Comment: *"As explicitly stated in the last section of the FAQ"* What FAQ? Can you link to it, please? I'm with Brad, I'm skeptical of this claim. Is this a question tagged [[meta-tag:faq]] on Meta? Or is this something in the Help Center? Who added it? What *precisely* does it say?

Comment: @CodyGray it's [this FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997), I also added the quote on the question. Also, it's added on [revision 19](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/86998/19), and then modified on [revision 31](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/86998/31)

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected, that doesn't say what it's being presented as saying in this question. It just says that question bans take the IP address into account. [The Meta Stack Overflow version of the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255584) states more succinctly: *"You* and others on your network *may be prevented from asking questions entirely."* Established accounts in good standing are not going to be subject to these restrictions. Jon would be unaffected.

Comment: Yeah, the flaw in this FAQ is that it *unconditionally* says that *everyone else* from the same IP will be blocked. I've made that edit in [my proposal for editing the ban FAQ](https://gist.github.com/gparyani/3941143fe93b54a7c1106f3c30417fc4).

Comment: I use Tor, and the worst I ever get is a recaptcha when I try to search on an SE site that I haven't joined.